# Must declare the scalar variable "@Station" with pyodbc UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server, numpy, pyodbc

```
Station = SN[0]
Asset = AN[0]
y = ASD[0]
z = ACD[0]

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM station')
cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE station
    SET ActualStartDate = y, ActualCompletionDate = z
    WHERE StationName = @Station and AssetNumber = @Asset
    ''')
conn.commit()
```

I am getting this error:

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@Station". (137) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I would like to get the values from 4 numpy arrays above, SN[0], AN[0], SCD[0] SSD[0] and use these values in the UPDATE Query.

Is it possible to execute this?

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but what happens if you change the variable "Station" to something else in case there's a conflict with sharing the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the pyodbc [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters), your parameter placeholders must be question marks and you must pass the parameter values along with the SQL command text in the `.execute()` call:

```py
sql = """\
UPDATE station
SET ActualStartDate = ?, ActualCompletionDate = ?
WHERE StationName = ? and AssetNumber = ?
"""
params = (y, z, Station, Asset)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```